# find rows in dataframe that are not NaN python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe called CentroidXY and I want to find the indexes of the rows in the column called 'X' that corresponds to numeric values (not NaN). I tried:

```
foo = CentroidXY.index[CentroidXY['X'] == int].tolist()
```

However this gives me back no indexes, although my column contains numeric values. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: What is the dtype of your column X? You compare to `int` here, but generally, NaNs work for floats, not ints.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
CentroidXY.index[CentroidXY['X'].notna()]
```